# Push changes on a submodule inside the outer repository instead of pushing them to the submodule itself

Tags: git, smartgit

I am working on my own git repository. It contains a third-party submodule. During my work I would like to change my repository and also some components from the submodule used by my repository. After pushing my commits, changes on my repository were saved as commits inside my repository and changes on the submodule were saved as commits on the currently checked out branch of the submodule.

Is it possible to save the changes on the submodule components inside my own repository? Because I have no write access to the third-party submodule I can just commit my changes locally. Hence I couldn’t provide my changes on the submodule components to other peoples, working on my repository.

If I could push the changes on the submodule components to my own repository, all other contributors would also see these changes.

Again, my main question is:
How do I push changes on a git submodule to my repository (the outer repository)? I need it, because the submodule is a third-party module, where I have no write access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clone the third-party repository
2. Change the things I would like to change
3. Pushed the adjusted repository to my own server (forked repository)
4. Added the adjusted repository to my main repository (the outer repository) as submodule

Benefit: I can push things to the forked repository on my own server

Answer (score 1):

You can't. What you could do is fork the submodule you are using so that you do have write access, and in your main project refer to that forked version instead.